# Magento 2 Checkout_module JS structure

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3, file-structure, magento2.4

I have been learning magento since past 2 months but i have been stuck at a point in learning .

What i can't understand is Why there are 3 folders in JS of checkout_module VIEW,ACTION,MODEL
are they for any reason or they just created it to keep file separate for better knowledge and understanding

Comment: If you need any files please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 source code (at least for the javascript part) separate folders depending on the use case. I'm assuming you talk about the `Magento_Checkout` module

Since Magento2 use [KnockoutJs](https://knockoutjs.com/) there is a `view` folder to contain view model of these components (there surely all have a `.html` in the template folder with the same path or so).

The `action` folder contain functions to call to perform "action" like making an order or adding an item to cart.

The `model` is often use to interact with the local storage or data object.

I don't think there's a convention on how to store your javascript files other than storing them in `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js` folder. I think it's better to organize your code like the code source.

Also I'm still learning so my answer may not be totally complete.